# ¿Como remover hash(#) de Url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Genero un hash con este código pero no puedo removerlo.

```
$('#terror').on('click', function() {
    window.location.hash='/terror';
});
```

Y obtengo esta URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/terror
```

Quiero removerla usando este código:

```
 $('#cTodos').on('click', function() {
   window.location.hash ='';
 });
```

Y obtengo esta URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/#
```

Nesecito dejarlo así:

```
 http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes, si estableces un un string vacío a `location.hash` lo que pasará es que se eliminará lo que hay después del hash pero este seguirá intacto. Si estableces un nuevo valor para `window.location` se recargará la página:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

La solución es simplemente reemplazar la URL por medio de la API History:

```
history.replaceState({}, null, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Como se explica en [MDN, "manipulando el historial del navegador"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method), puedes usar `pushState` de la API de history.

```
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

Debes tener en cuenta que si bien esto no regarga la pagina, si el usario recargase la pagina con <kbd>F5</kbd> el navegador ira a la nueva URL cambiada y no a la original.